# Reduce number of output variables in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

My model is currently roughly 2000 equations, and the simulation period is a couple of weeks. I'm using the OpenModelica Connection Editor.

The problem I'm facing is the huge amount of output variables, and I've had the plot window crash a couple of times.

The question is, therefore, how can I reduce the number of output variables?

I'm only really interested in 20-50 of them. I'm aware that I can remove parameter output by making them protected, but I haven't been able to locate any similar tricks for variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simulating the model via command line then take a look at `variableFilter` argument of `simulate` command https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/OpenModelica.Scripting.simulate.html.

If you are using OMEdit then `Simulation->Simulation Setup->Output->Variable Filter (Optional)`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I After seeing it's called "filter variables", I came across this link [link](https://openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/1227-filtering-variables-in-simulation), which is also quite useful.

However I still can't seem to make it actually work. Let's the variable I want is P, in component abc, then I would expect writing abc.P in the filter variables line to work. If I do that it simply removes all variables (but not the parameters).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, protected isn't limited to parameters. Here's an example duplicating Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Examples.SignConvention and protecting everything but mass1
Tested in Dymola 2017FD01 with pedantic mode (so it should work in OpenModelica as well); it works fine, and gives only mass1 parameters and variables in the simulation results

```
model SignConvention "Examples for the used sign conventions."
 extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
 Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Mass mass1(
   L=1,
   s(fixed=true),
   v(fixed=true),
   m=1) a;

protected
 Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Force force1
   a;
 Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant constant1(k=1) a;
 Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Mass mass2(
   L=1,
   s(fixed=true),
   v(fixed=true),
   m=1) a;
 Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Force force2
   a;
 Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant constant2(k=1) a;
 Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Mass mass3(
   L=1,
   s(fixed=true),
   v(fixed=true),
   m=1) a;
 Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Force force3(useSupport=true)
   a;
 Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant constant3(k=1) a;
 Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Fixed fixed
   a;

equation
...
```

Comment: In the OpenModelica Connection Editor, protecting variables usually doesn't work, partly because of aliasing for the variables. Unfortunately, the 'annotation(HideResult=true)' also doesn't work